# Clarifying what "children" are in backdraftjs

Tags: javascript, backdraftjs

What are `children` of a backdraftjs component? I would have expected them to be whatever's in the top level of the tree but that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a component:

```
export class MarxBrothers {
    bdElements() {
        return e.div(
            e.span('groucho'),
            e.span('harpo'),
            e.span(
                e.div(
                    e.span(
                        e(Button, {label: 'chico'})
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            e(Button, {label: 'zeppo'})
        );
    }
}
```

Where the component is `this`...

- `this.children` is ONLY the two Button components, 'chico' and 'zeppo'. Regular dom elements like `span` or `div` are not included in `children`, and `children` seems to dig down through the tree until it reaches a component.
- `this.delChildren()` deletes the two buttons and leaves the rest of the content.